# Find volume of solid using method of cylindrical shells (Almost solved)

Tags: calculus

$y= (x+2)^2$, $x=1$,  $x=0$ , $y=0$ about $x$-axis

$\text{Shell radius} = y$

$\text{Shell height} =  1-x =  1- \sqrt y + 2 = 3- \sqrt y$

Limit =  4 to 9

I got the answer $\frac{131}5 \pi$

Q1. I just want to know is this correct?
Q2. I am confused here its height should be $1-x$ or $3-x$?

Comment: The region being rotated is not fully described. Is it the region **above** the $x$=axis, below $y=(x+2)^2$, between $x=0$ and $x=1$? Shells is not best strategy then. If you want to use shells, need to add a cylinder, plus the stuff $y=4$ to $y=9$. For that part, your radius and height are right.

Comment: Region bounded by y= (2+x)^2 , x=0 , x=1 , y=0  forgot to include in the question y=0

Comment: The volume is $\frac{311}{5}\pi$.

Comment: Could you please tell me what should be the radius here??

Comment: I have a typo above, it is $211$, not $311$.

Comment: I wrote it above, that you were right, it is $y$. However, using the shell method that only takes care of the part above $y=4$. As I mentioned earlier, need to add a cylinder. But the easy way to find the volume, as you know, is $\int_0^1 \pi(x+2)^4\,dx$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shell method](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus/solid_revolution_topic/shell-method/v/shell-method-for-rotating-around-horizontal-line) says that we have to find the following integral: $$16\pi+\int_{y=4}^92\pi xy dy=16\pi+\int_4^92\pi (3-\sqrt{y})ydy= \frac{211}{5}\pi\approx 132.5752$$

[image]

Comment: Why use $\approx$?

Comment: What is this 16π  for??